# Tips for share content of my website on facebook

Tags: facebook, share

I have a job portal website and on that I have a facebook button named as share in fb. I want that when user clicks on that button the that specific job description of my webpage should share on his wall.

```
<a rel='nofollow' href='http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://testing.com/current_openings.php?JobId=".$jobiid."' target='_blank'>share in fbk</a>
```

Above link go to share page,but its content is coming from webpage about us page,not specific content.

Comment: Debug the URL at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Answer (score 0):

Set the meta tags for each site you want to be shareable.

Put them in the HTML Header like [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

The properties include descriptive meta-data about the article that we specifically want to present when

Comment: thank you for your coment.Is it possible share latest job post every time using this.please reply me